# Inject class level typeparam to generic method

Tags: c#

I want to create a generic repository structure that both can be applied to databases or tables so that I can both have one repository per database or one repository for a specific table. Therefore I created an interface `IRepository`

```
public interface IRepository
{
    bool SaveChangesAutomatically { get; set; }
    
    Task InsertAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    Task InsertRangeAsync<TEntity>([NotNull] params TEntity[] entities) where TEntity : class;

    Task DeleteAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    Task DeleteRangeAsync<TEntity>([NotNull] params TEntity[] entities) where TEntity : class;
    Task DeleteWhereAsync<TEntity>(Func<TEntity, bool> condition) where TEntity : class;

    Task UpdateAsync<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class;
    Task UpdateRangeAsync<TEntity>([NotNull] params TEntity[] entities) where TEntity : class;

    TResult Query<TEntity, TResult>(Expression<Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, TResult>> query) where TEntity : class;
    Task SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The type parameter `TEntity` is not on class level because a deriving database repository is not bound to a specific entity type because it contains multiple tables of different entity types.

The interface is implemented in an abstract class `Repository`

```
public abstract class Repository<TDbContext> : IRepository where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected TDbContext DbContext { get; }
    
    public virtual bool SaveChangesAutomatically { get; set; }

    protected Repository(TDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.DbContext = dbContext;
    }

    // implement IRepository members

    protected abstract DbSet<TEntity> UseTable<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
}
```

This class introduces the DB context but implements the members independent of it. It gets the Table to use not from the DB context but from another method called `UseTable`.

This class then should be inherited by both the `DatabaseRepository` and the `TableRepository` class. The `DatabaseRepository` implements the method `UseTable` by returning the first property
of the DB context of type `DbSet<TEntity>`. The `TableRepository` should return a specific DbSet-Property.

Because of this, a generic type parameter in the methods of a `TableRepository` is not necessary anymore because it uses always the same table. That's why I want to restrict the type parameter to only be the entity type of the table, so the method can actually return the `DbSet` which is not possible by now.

In the end it should look somehow like this:

```
public abstract class TableRepository<TDbContext, TEntity> : Repository<TDbContext> where TDbContext : DbContext where TEntity : class
{
    public TableRepository(TDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext) { }
    
    protected abstract override DbSet<TEntity> UseTable<TEntity>(); // Does not use class level type parameter but introduces own.
}
```

And then the final class for a specific table

```
public class UserTableRepository : TableRepository<ApplicationDbContext, IdentityUser>
{
    public UserTableRepository(ApplicationDbContext dbContext) : base(dbContext) { }
    
    protected override DbSet<IdentityUser> UseTable() => this.DbContext.Users;
}
```

Is it somehow possible to achieve this behavior? It also would be okay the other way around, so type parameter `TEntity` in `IRepository` and `Repository` up to `DatabaseRepository` and in here only `TDbContext` and allow any `TEntity`.

Comment: It should work.  A row of dbContext is a set of properties while a row in a DataTable is a collection of columns.  So you need to be able to convert from columns to properties.  Also with a DataTable you need to use AsEnumerable() while a dbContext is already an enumerable list.

Comment: @Neil First the other methods are async because if `SaveChangesAutomatically` is true they call `SaveChangesAsync` on their own, except for Query which is not async. Second, I have to create a custom repository because we are currently switching from Linq2Db to EF and I have to add an additional layer

Comment: And regardless of whether that makes sense in relation to EF, I would still be interested in how I can solve this problem

Comment: @jdweng I don't know what you mean. I never mentioned a DataTable

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? The whole idea of "a generic repository structure that both can be applied to databases or tables " just sounds like it introduces problems, not solving any.

Comment: I ask you to just focus on the problem I already explained in the question, whether there is such a language feature or not, so whether I can somehow specify this fixed type parameter or not. Not even necessarily the way I did it. Just because the code includes EF doesn't mean the question is about EF. Everything else is helpful tips that can be added after the question has been answered.

Comment: The reason you don't want to save changes in an insert or update, is that you may want to update several objects at the same time.  These should be written to the database in a single transaction.   If, every time you insert a record it immedetly gets saved to the database, then you lose this 'atomic' operation, and you will end up with records that are out of sync.